# How to manually correlate cookies in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to performance test an app that uses some high level security protocols (like Kerberos to name one)

I already correlated the tokens sent back and forth, but now run into an issue with the cookies.

In the request following a previous response, the app when used by a user in a browser, passes a cookie + a chunk of token from the previous response.

I already enabled cookies as variables in the user.properties file of JMeter.

JMeter's cookie manager does not handle this well so I need to proceed with a manual cookie handling and add the chunk of token to the end of it somehow.

But I am unsure how to achieve this and can't seem to find how to go about this online either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child to your request.
2. Add this code:

   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

   Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("chunkToken", "value", "domain", "path", true, Long.MAX_VALUE);
   sampler.getCookieManager().add(myCookie);

Comment: Will this work even if I keep my Cookie Manager active?
And can I supply variables taken from the previous response like:

`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;`

`Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("${chunkToken}", "${value}", "domain", "path", true, Long.MAX_VALUE);
sampler.getCookieManager().add(myCookie);`

Comment: Sure, it will work with Cookie Manager.

Comment: Use vars.get("VARIABLE_NAME") to get variable value in JSR223 Sampler